# Leaflet default markers not showing in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I have been using Leaflet for R for years with no problems.  This morning, the default markers are no longer appearing on my maps, even though the popups appear on the hovers.

I can reproduce the behavior with the simplest built-in utilities:

```
library(leaflet)
data(quakes)
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(mag))
```

[image]

I have deleted the leaflet folder from R and reinstalled the package (v2.1.0), but still get the same results.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this and how I can troubleshoot/fix it?  I'm considering deleting and reinstalling R, but would love to know if there's a better option.

Thanks!

Comment: apparently, the images of the marker http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.3.1/images/marker-icon.png is not reachable.. I suggest using `addCircleMarkers()`

Comment: Thanks @Wimpel -- I've posted an issue on [their github repo](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/issues/790)

Answer (score 2):

Package maintainer has fixed this in the version posted to CRAN yesterday.

Comment: It's failing again today.  Trying to access the url today shows "Access Denied". Circle markers continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

As @Wimpel said in the comments, you could use the `addCircleMarkers()` command. You can use the following code:

```
library(leaflet)
data(quakes)
leaflet(data = quakes[1:20,]) %>% addTiles() %>%
  addCircleMarkers(~long, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(mag), label = ~as.character(mag))
```

Output:

[image]